# BigQuery if table exists query not working?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I'm working on a query that will return a different result based on if a table is found. Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(IF(COUNT(table_id) > 0, 1, 0)) AS found
FROM `table.__TABLES__` 
WHERE table_id = 'app_events_20170207'
```

The issue I'm having is

> Error: Aggregations of aggregations are not allowed at [2:3]

I'm probably missing something simple but can't seem to pinpoint it. Any help would be great, thanks!

The end product will be a query based on if the table is found, run one query, if not, run another.

For example in pseudo code:

```
if (count(table_id) > 0, select * from table1, select * from table2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have here aggregation over aggregation - which obviously does not work
From the other hand it looks like what you want - count found tables - easily can be achieved via below

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(table_id) AS found
FROM `table.__TABLES__` 
WHERE table_id = 'app_events_20170207'
```

> Answer for updated question

Assuming that output of (select * from table1) and (select * from table2) have same schema - you can use something like below

```
#standardSQL
WITH switch AS (
  SELECT 
    COUNT(table_id) AS found
  FROM `table.__TABLES__` 
  WHERE table_id = 'app_events_20170207'  
)
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ((SELECT MAX(found) FROM switch) > 0)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE ((SELECT MAX(found) FROM switch) = 0)
```

You can check how it behaves with below dummy data:

```
#standardSQL
WITH table1 AS (
  SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b
),
table2 AS (
  SELECT 3 AS a, 4 AS b
),
switch AS (
  SELECT 
    COUNT(table_id) AS found
  FROM `table.__TABLES__` 
  WHERE table_id = 'app_events_20170207'  
)
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ((SELECT MAX(found) FROM switch) > 0)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE ((SELECT MAX(found) FROM switch) = 0)
```

Comment: This query will kinda give me what I want, but not exactly. I'll edit the post and explain here. I want to run a different query based on if the table is found or not.

Comment: @JoeScotto - you should provide full example of what you would wanted to achive! Otherwise it is just shooting into the air. I can give you what i think you need but it will end up you meant something else. To avoid this back and forth - just provide good example!